# Checking Injectivity and Surjectivity on set of functions

Tags: calculus

Let $C_0$ be the set of all continuous functions $f: [0,1] \rightarrow R$ and $C_1$ be the set of all differentiable functions $g:[0,1] \rightarrow R$ such that the derivative $g'$ is continuous. If   $T: C_1 \rightarrow C_0$ is defined by $T(g)=g'$, the

(a) T is one-to-one and onto

(b) T is one-to-one but not onto

(c) T is onto but not one-to-one

(d) T is neither one-to-one nor onto

Source: ISI QROR 2021 18th July

In my view, T cannot be one-to-one as two functions who differ by a constant will be mapped to the same function.

Comment: Given a function $f$ in $C_0$ you wish to find some $g$ in $C_1$ with $g' = f$. So the question is: Does every function in $C_0$ admit a primitive? Do you know the answer formulated this way?

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see the relevance of the fact that $C_0$ contains continuous functions whose derivative is not continuous. The map $T$ is onto because, if $f\in C_0$ and if $F(t)=\int_0^tf(x)\,\mathrm dx$, then $T(F)=f$. But, yes, $T$ is not injective. To justify that, it would be better to provide a concrete example (such as the constant functions $0$ and $1$). So, the correct option is (c).

Answer (score 2):

$T$ is onto as according to [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) for any $f \in \mathcal C^0$,

$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \ dt$$ is an inverse image of $f$ under $T$.

However $T$ is not one-to-one as any two functions that differ by a constant have the same image under $T$.

Finally, the correct answer is (c).